# Android Dagger 2 Dependency not being injected

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

i'm trying to use Dagger 2 into my apps but i'm having some problems regarding the entities repository and i haven't figured it out what i'm missing.

Here is my Application Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                AndroidModule.class,
                RepositoryModule.class
        }
)

public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(AndroidApplication app);
    IDependenceyRepository dependencyRepository();
}
```

My modules:

```
@Module
public class RepositoryModule {
    @Provides @Singleton IDependenceyRepository provideDependendencyRepository(Context context) {
        return new DependencyRepository(context);
    }
}

@Module
public class AndroidModule {
    private final AndroidApplication app;

    public AndroidModule(AndroidApplication app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

My AndroidApplication:

```
public class AndroidApplication extends Application {
    private ApplicationComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupGraph();
    }

    private void setupGraph() {
        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .androidModule(new AndroidModule(this))
                .repositoryModule(new RepositoryModule())
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }

    public ApplicationComponent component() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

And here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject
    IDependenceyRepository repository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.testRepository();
    }

    private void testRepository() {
        Dependency dep = new Dependency();
        dep.setDescription("XXX");
        dep.setName("AAAA");

        try {
            repository.save(dep);
            Log.d("", repository.queryAll().get(0).getName());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What happens is that i'm getting a null pointer exception into the repository. He is not being injected.

If i add this line though:

```
repository = ((AndroidApplication) getApplication()).component().dependencyRepository();
```

It works, but the point of the DI it's not to have to worry about this, or am im wrong about that?

I've tried some other example and tutorials but haven't managed to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, that would pretty much defeat the purpose of having the `@Inject` annotation in the first place. I've only played with Dagger for about a day now, but I think you need to do something like that in your `Activity`: `((AndroidApplication) getApplication()).component().inject(this)` and also add the line `void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);` to your `ApplicationComponent`. But that _has_ puzzled me a bit - I'd love to see other answers, too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

david.mihola's comment is correct: in order to be able to have @Inject fields initialized, you need to have a method (typically `void inject(MyClass)`) in your component.

It's worth noting (not specifically for your question, but it could come up) that if you have a base class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((AndroidApplication) getApplication()).component().inject(this);
    }
}
```

and in your component:

```
void inject(BaseActivity);
```

Injecting into a subclass that has it's own @Inject fields *won't* work:

```
public class ActualActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Inject IDependenceyRepository repo;
}
```

This is because Dagger needs to know the concrete classes that will be injected at *compile time*, not runtime (like Dagger 1 could do).

Comment: To generalize, you will need to perform manual members injection on _any_ object created by the platform.  This includes implementations of `Application`, `Activity`, `Fragment`, et. al.

Comment: If i'm going to use this repository across multiple activities, do i have to have an inject method in my Component for each activity that will use it?

Comment: @Gilson - correct. Any class you write for which you don't own the lifecycle (like the ones @gk5885 mentioned) and you want to accessible via members injection (`@Inject SomeObject myObject;` as opposed to constructor injection) must have it's own inject method. Dagger needs to know those ahead of time, and the only way for it to know is for you to make that explicit in your component.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Could you maybe mention a few "best practices" as to how to pass the `Component` around? Is `onAttach` a good place for a `Fragment` to get it from its `Activity`? I've seen it done in `onActivityCreated`,  but then ran into problems because I often do stuff at the end of `onCreateView` that would already need the injected objects...

Comment: "This is because Dagger needs to know the concrete classes that will be injected at compile time, not runtime" you saved my day thanks!!!
So what should I do if I want to inject so many classes that have the same PARENT CLASS ??